# Paths problem works '/file.xyz' doesn't work '../file.xyz' on the Web not in localhost?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Why does path like `'/file.xyz'` works on the web but does not in localhost?

I'm using Xampp

In localhost I had to change it to `'../file.xyz'`

Comment: you need to clarify if you mean frontend access (via url - e.g. a link) or backend access (via file e.g. filesize/file_exists)

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses a backslash rather than a forward slash.  Use `realpath($path)` to get the correct path for the system.

http://www.php.net/realpath